# How to delete the content of github repository?

Tags: xcode, git, github, push, pull

I wrongly pushed my code using Xcode toolbar into my repository on github. now, I want to delete all files in my master branch, but not the repository. Then I want to pull my code into repository this time instead of pushing. Does any one know how to delete all contents of master branch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In git, you can't delete the content of a branch. All you can do is to push a commit that removes all your files.
If you want to start over from a clean repository, you have to delete the current one a create a new one with the same name for example.

Comment: can you explain how to push a commit that remove all files?

Comment: Did you try it: Is it possible to remove a repo and create a new one with the same name?

Comment: @Quentin some one else created this repository which is an private one, so I think I can not delete it.

Comment: @MKH well, you delete all the files in your working copy and you commit those changes...

Comment: Then it would probable make sense to remove the parentheses in your answer, however, a useful information.

Comment: I do not know how to use the terminal statement. before that, I used the Xcode interface to push my code, I think that I should use terminal statement for trying your solution.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with Terminal, you can use GitHub's mac application to make your life easier: https://mac.github.com/

Comment: @Wolf I delete all files and push my changes, now I want to pull my code. when I tried pulling it did not worked, plus it deletes all my file in  the project.

Comment: @MKH Sorry, I'm not really experienced with GitHub, but interested, that's why I tried to further the clarification of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to support quentin's answer, adding the git commands:

1. Keep a backup of the local repository folder and remove all its contents.
2. Add these changes to commit

```
$ git add *
```

3. Add a Commit message

```
$ git commit "Remove everything"
```

4. Push changes

```
$ git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool that helps with that ..  and it doesn’t require you to enter your auth token since netlify handles that for you :)
check out
https://repo-cleaner.netlify.com

Answer (score 0):

Delete the git repository and create new one with the same name